# ¿Cómo llamar a una función de otro archivo.py desde main.py si dicha función ya tiene un argumento?

Tags: python, funciones

¿Cómo llamo a ésta función (con un argumento "eye" ya establecido) desde main.py?

```
def eye_aspect_ratio(eye):
    # compute the euclidean distances between the two sets of
    # vertical eye landmarks (x, y)-coordinates
    A = dist.euclidean(eye[1], eye[5])
    B = dist.euclidean(eye[2], eye[4])

    # compute the euclidean distance between the horizontal
    # eye landmark (x, y)-coordinates
    C = dist.euclidean(eye[0], eye[3])

    # compute the eye aspect ratio
    ear = (A + B) / (2.0 * C)

    # return the eye aspect ratio
    return ear
```

Desde el archivo main.py:

```
from Parpadeo_Ojos import eye_aspect_ratio

eye_aspect_ratio()
```

Resultado de esto:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*******\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    eye_aspect_ratio()
TypeError: eye_aspect_ratio() missing 1 required positional argument: 'eye'
```

Si añado el argumento **eye** a la función desde main.py, tengo el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*******\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    eye_aspect_ratio(eye)
NameError: name 'eye' is not defined
```

¿Alguien sabría cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: El argumento de la función es una tupla de seis valores. En el `main.py` tienes que crear esa tupla `mi_ojito = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` antes de llamar con `eye_aspect_ratio(mi_ojito)`. Tu misión es poner los datos correctos.

Comment: `eye` es solo un nombre que existe sólo dentro de la función `eye_aspect_ratio()` para referirse al **valor** que le pases desde otra función cuando la invoques. Es misión de otra función proporcionar ese valor. Puedes hacerlo directamente (por ejemplo `eye_aspect_ratio([(0,0,0), (1,1,1), (0,1,0), (2,2,2), (2,1,0), (0,1,2)])`, o a través de otra variable intermedia, como `o = [(0,0,0), (1,1,1), (0,1,0), (2,2,2), (2,1,0), (0,1,2)]; eye_aspect_ratio(o)`. Naturalmente lo que signifiquen esos números es cosa tuya. He supuesto que son coordenadas 3D de 6 puntos.